# if I were you, I would not make a better choice

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning

Is it right sentence when I want to express that I totally agree with the decision which my friend made?

> if I were you, I would not make a better choice!

Also what is better & right shortage

> "I'd not" or "I wouldn't"

Thanks.

Comment: "I'd not" = "I wouldn't" = "I would not", no difference whatsoever.  Phrase "I could not" might sound even a bit stronger than "I would not".

Comment: @VictorBazarov but *I'd not* is also a contraction for *I had not*

Comment: @Usernew : but "**had** not" requires "**made**" rather than "**make**".

Comment: @VictorBazarov correct, but I was talking in general sense :(

Comment: @Usernew : but I **wasn't**.

Comment: *I couldn't've done any better* is more concise and probably is a more natural way to phrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I were you, I would not make a better choice!

It implies that you **could have** made a better choice, but you were not willing to do for some reason.

Try this:

> If I were you, I would not have made a better choice.